# How can I use mpi with kubernetes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes, mpi, google-kubernetes-engine

My goal is simply to run `mpirun` on all pods and make it work.

For the moment, I can

1. Create a GKE cluster with 2 nodes;
2. Deploy one pod to each node using my own docker image;
3. Ssh to pods/nodes and check status.

But when I run `mpirun -np 2 -host 10.112.0.6,10.112.1.7` on both pods, nothing shows up but `Warning: Permanently added '10.112.0.6' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.`

I know that something certainly goes wrong here, but I don't know where. I have a few ideas:

1. Should I bind pod ports to node ports and limit the mpi port range?
2. Should I include create a network policy?

Thanks a lot!